# SQL server count datasets in different results without subselect

Tags: sql, sql-server

following table (`STAT_BC`):

```
ID (int), Date (dateTime), NodeID (int)
```

---

Now i want to do an analyze like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(SB2.NODEID) as all, COUNT(SB1.NODEID)as y2010, SB1.NODEID
FROM STAT_BC SB1 
JOIN STAT_BC SB2 ON SB1.ID = SB2.ID WHERE YEAR(SB2.Date)=2010 
GROUP BY SB1.NODEID
```

My experience is to get all NodeID with the counting of all and the year 2010
Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a case statement to return null when the year is not 2010

```
SELECT COUNT(SB1.NODEID) as all, COUNT(case when YEAR(SB1.Date)=2010 then SB1.NODEID else null end)as y2010, SB1.NODEID
FROM STAT_BC SB1 
GROUP BY SB1.NODEID
```

Comment: When applying case why do we need to have self join, your query should work without self join .... So i guess we do not need SB2 with case ...

Answer (score 0):

I think below query should give correct results...

```
SELECT SBALL.Count as allNodes, SB2010.Count as y2010,SB2010.NODEID
(
 SELECT COUNT(SB.NODEID) as Count, SB.NODEID
   FROM STAT_BC SB 
  GROUP BY SB.NODEID
) SBALL
JOIN 
(
 SELECT COUNT(SB.NODEID) as Count, SB.NODEID
  FROM STAT_BC SB 
 WHERE YEAR(SB.Date)=2010
 GROUP BY SB.NODEID
) SB2010 ON SBALL.NODEID = SB2010.NODEID
```

You can choose outer join in case you want even those nodes which are not in 2010. And as a practice we should not use Keywords as column identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count all it with one select, then do:

```
SELECT 
  sb.NODEID, 
  (select count(*)from STAT_BC sb1 where sb1.NODEID=sb.NODEID) as all,
  (select count(*)from STAT_BC sb2 where sb2.NODEID=sb.NODEID and YEAR(sb2.Date)=2010) as y2010
FROM 
  STAT_BC sb
```